# SSH asking for password even after keys set up

Tags: ssh

I am trying to setup ssh keys via [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) method.

Here is the starting point on server

```
server:~/.ssh$ ls   
#shows empty
```

Here is the starting point on client

```
client: ~/.ssh$ls #shows empty dir
```

On client, I run

```
$ ssh-keygen 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
26:25:e0:2f:90:d8:d9:fb:79:03:5d:99:a1:61:a9:dc me@machine
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|    .   o..      |
| o = . ..o +     |
|. = o..oo +      |
|   . oo+E.       |
|    o + S        |
|     o =         |
|      o o        |
|       . .       |
|                 |
+-----------------+

$ ls
id_rsa      id_rsa.pub
```

So far so good. So then I run

```
$ ssh-copy-id -p 3457 me@server #running on non standard port
The authenticity of host '[server]:3457 ([104.131.226.216]:3457)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 1c:52:db:19:22:b8:47:18:24:ad:07:2f:e5:d3:c4:8e.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
me@server's password: 

Number of key(s) added:        1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh -p '3457' 'me@server'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

I run `ssh -p '3457' 'me@server'` and see that `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` shows that the keys match. I logout, trying sshing in again.  But it STILL asks me for a password -- even after running `sudo service ssh restart` on server. I'm not sure what else I can do. What are the next steps?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have that key already loaded in your session

```
$ ssh-add
```

It should print ~/.ssh/id_rsa

In case you get an error saying "*couldn't get a connection to the authentication agent*" then execute

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
```

and repeat `ssh-add`

The former should be enough, but I also reccomend having an ssh config file. For this, edit (or create) an `~/.ssh/config` file with contents

```
Host server
    HostName 104.131.226.216
    User me
    Port 3457
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: is this all on the client or the server?

Comment: everything happens in your local

Comment: that is not solving it. any other ideas?

Comment: Try adding -vvv to your ssh command to enhance output's verbosity. Make sure your key has 0700 permission

Comment: looks like there is an additional config file located at $/etc/ssh_config   Client is on OSX. Can I delete that SSH file?

Answer (score 0):

Are the file access permissions for the authorized_keys file `644` (`-rw-r--r--`)?

(I would leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough points)

Answer (score 0):

**eval `ssh-agent`**

After that, add identity to key file

**ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/xxx.pem**

After execution of above command it should not prompt you for a password

You need to do this every time if you use a new bash prompt. For that one do one thing.

Edit the above lines in **$HOME/.bashrc** file